# BIRT base64 image generation using xml input

Tags: eclipse, base64, birt, birt-emitter, birt-deapi

My XML input will have a base64 encoded Version of an image. The image is dynamic in nature an cannot be embedded using image-embed image option in BIRT. I am using Version >4 BIRT. I tried the URI option With input as base64 but its not working in the preview of PDF. Can any body throw some lights[see how i added. dataimage tag is my base64encoded data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wS1jz.png)

Answer (score 2):

Finally I am able to figure it out.

1. The encoded data of xml needs to be decoded and passed on to a table row.
2. `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64(row["dcpimage"]).`
3. It will not appear in the template but will properly refelct in pdf and html preview mode

[image]